# Can't figure out how to use all() to work in my "code"

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
m = range(1, 2000000, 2)
sum1 = 2
for x in xrange(1, 2000000, 2):
    for y in m:
        if x != y:
            if x%y == 0:
                m.remove(x)
            if all(x%y != 0):
                sum1 += x
```

That's what I've written. It's about a problem, trying to add all the primes bellow two million. My problem is in the all() statement. What I want to happen is to check if x is a prime; that is true only if every x%y gives a remainder.

Also if I use a can I use a statement (break?) to stop the loop if y > x/3 like so:

```
 m = range(1, 2000000, 2)
sum1 = 2
for x in xrange(1, 2000000, 2):
    for y in m:
        if y > x/3:
            break
        else:
            if x != y:
                if x%y == 0:
                    m.remove(x)
                if all(x%y != 0):
                    sum1 += x
```

Comment: [all()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) takes an iterable for argument.

Comment: What do you think `all` does? It looks like your code would be correct without it.

Comment: I find it really weird you use `range()` in one instance then `xrange()` in another. You should always use `xrange()` unless you actually *need* a list (very rare) or you are using Python 3.x, where `range()` works as `xrange()` does in 2.x. It also generally makes your code neater to turn nested `if` statements into one with an `and` - e.g: `if (not x == y) and (x % y == 0):`. Likewise you could use `for x, y in itertools.product(xrange(...), 2)` here as your loop for more clarity.

Comment: Also, I can't help but ask, why is *code* in quotes in your title? Is it not real code? It's really weird to put them there.

Comment: No number is divisible for any number greater than its half. You can save a lot of time in your code if you include that fact. Also any prime number greater than 5 ends in 1,3,7,9. You are testing a lot more than you should.

Answer (score 10):

You have to pass a sequence or iterable to `all` -- it just tests whether or not all the items passed to it evaluate as true. Here's the right way to use `all`:

```
>>> all([True, True, True])
True
>>> all([True, False, True])
False
>>> all([x > 5 for x in range(10)])
False
>>> all([x > 5 for x in range(6, 10)])
True
>>> all(x > 5 for x in range(6, 10))
True
```

That last one is the best, because it takes advantage of [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

However, your call to `all` in your code is pointless. The idea behind your code, it seems to me, is to go through all the values in `m` and remove those that are divisible by any number between 2 and 2000000. Once you've done that, `m` will contain only prime numbers.

Of course, your code still won't work if you remove `all`. That's because you're actually testing whether each number in `m` is divisible by the numbers `[1, 3, 5, 7...1999999]`. (That's the sequence signified by `xrange(1, 2000000, 2)`. Because you start at `1`, and everything is divisible by `1`, your code will count nothing as prime. And then, once you remove `1` from that sequence, anything divisible by `2` will be counted as prime by your code! You should think more carefully about which numbers you actually have to test in your inner loop.

Finally, you should think about how many loops this code will complete. Even once you have this working, it will take a *very long time* to generate a result. You should test it on smaller numbers first; and then, you should think about how to reduce the number of loops. (And -- *only after* you've thought about it a bit -- read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).)

But once you have this working, all you have to do is call `sum` on your list of primes.

Comment: Note that calling `all()` on a list comprehension is a bad idea. A generator expression will be the better option as `all()` short-circuits when it finds a value that evaluates to `False` - as such, when you use a generator expression, you compute only the values that are `True` - with a list comprehension, you generate them all beforehand, then potentially fail out straight away. It's also worth noting the difference between elements needing to *evaluate* to `True` as opposed to *being* `True`. (`all(["test"])` is `True` as a non-empty string *evaluates* to `True` despite not *being* `True`).

Comment: @Lattyware, yes, there's some nuance missing from this, which is to some degree a pedagogical simplification. I incorporated your point about evaluation. But I would phrase your point about list comprehensions differently. It's not a "bad idea" to use list comprehensions here; it's just not _as good_ as passing a generator expression in most cases. I'm assuming that the OP isn't familiar with these constructs, which may not be correct; but if it is, a gentle progression from lists to list comprehensions to generator expressions seems like the right way to introduce them.

Comment: As there is never a situation where a list comprehension is a better idea than a generator expression, and in most situations it's worse, I would say it's a bad idea to get into the habit of using anything but generator expressions there. Naturally, I'm not expecting you to detail every point about `all()` exhaustively, but I just thought I'd make note of a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `all` is incorrect, if you look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) for it, it takes an iterable.

What you may be trying to do is use a generator expression, something of the form:

```
sum(x**2 for x in range(10))
```

which is very similar to the list comprehension

```
[x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

However, use of `all` in this manner wouldn't suddenly stop the generator expression, if it found a divisor. Use of `any` and checking for `x == 0` would stop sooner, but as the code is currently formatted, would check for many divisors before deeming something prime.

This would be more appropriate:

```
primes = []
MAX = 2000000

number = 2
while number < MAX:
    for prime in primes:
        if number % prime == 0:
            number += 1
            continue

    primes.append(number)
    number += 1

total = sum(primes)
```

Answer (score 0):

`all()` takes an iterable for an argument. In your situation, you would use it like this:

```
all(x%y for y in m)
```

where `x%y for y in m` is a generator expression. 
If I have an iterable

```
[item1, item2, item3, item4...]
```

`all(iterable)` is equivalent to:

```
item1 and item2 and item3 and item4...'
```